# app stucks when appends data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a mobile application. I use Angular and Ionic and the app's idea is to have feed with posts. When the user reach 70% ( for example) of the feed, I append new posts to the view. I have 5 posts from the beginning and append 5 posts each time. Even after the first 5 appended posts, the app stucks for half a second. If I am scrolling fast when I reach 70%, the scroll suddenly stops and the app stucks for 0.5 second, then I can scroll again.

This is how I am implementing the functionality:

```
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
      <div ng-include src="'js/post/post.html'"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ion-infinite-scroll immediate-check="false" on-infinite="appendPosts()" distance="30%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.appendPosts = function() {
  $scope.postsFeedPage = $scope.postsFeedPage + 1;
  Home.loadPosts($scope.postsFeedPage);
};

$scope.$watch(function(){
  return Home.getPosts();
}, function () {
  $scope.posts = Home.getPosts();
});
```

**Service**

```
  var posts = [];

  this.getPosts = function() {
    return posts;
  };

  this.loadPosts = function(page) {
    return $http({
      url: Server.url + '/api/posts', 
      method: 'GET',
      params: {page: page, token: $rootScope.user.authentication_token }
    }).success(function (data) {
      posts = posts.concat(JSON.parse(data.posts));
    });
  };
```

Any idea what is the problem and how I can fix this issue? If the problem is in Angular's performance, maybe I should use somehow RequireJS to optimize rendering process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem of performance and there are some solution you can try :

- [One-time binding](http://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/) : One time binding increase performanc, but in the case of infinite scroll, i didn't tested if this work/better. Try the following code:

  ```
   <div ng-repeat="post in ::posts">
    <div ng-include src="'js/::post/::post.html'"></div>
   </div>
  ```
- [Track by method](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm): Track by methode use a unique identifier and this can increase performance. Try this :

  ```
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts track by post.id">
       <div ng-include src="'js/post/post.html'"></div>
    </div>
  ```
- [Collection-repeat](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/): Ionic made a directive which allows an app to show huge lists of items much more performantly than ng-repeat. (Edit: this is the solution for this case).

  ```
    <div collection-repeat="post in posts">
       <div ng-include src="'js/post/post.html'"></div>
    </div>
  ```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have already tried your first solution. I have tried the same one and ng-repeat-once directive https://github.com/sumitchawla/ng-repeat-once . Unfortunately they don't work. If I understand their logic, when you have a list, you cannot modify it. My list with object is empty from the beginning and then I execute request to get first posts and then new requests for every 5 posts, so when I use this fix, the app stucks with empty posts and shows loading icon. The other fix doesn't fix the problem too. The app still stucks when appends new posts.

Comment: When i see your code in (controller), you are loading data from your server at each scroll ? It could be better if you load every data and store it in local variable and use this local variable to display post no ?

Comment: Yep, I am loading data on every scroll to the bottom. It's not possible to load all data and store it in local variable because my app can have 1 million posts for example. So it's not a possible solution.

Comment: Oh i see the problem, yes i didn't know that you can have that much posts :) . So Ionic made a directive ( collection-repeat ) wich increase performance when there is a lot of data. have you tried it?

Comment: Nope, I didn't know about this directive. I will try it in a minute :)

Comment: Great i add it to my answer :)

Comment: btw do you have an idea how can I add dynamic height to collection-item?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79505/discussion-between-carton-and-user1107922).